# Setting up docker on the mac: Cannot connect via localhost

Tags: macos, docker, virtual-machine

I'm just setting up docker on my Mac. The installation worked and I got some containers running (following the getting-stared guide), but now I want to connect with my browser to localhost, to show a web app.

For that I'm following this guide: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/usingdocker/

In the last section it is said, that you simple go with your browser to: localhost:XXXXX wheras XXXXX is the port, that you found out using the command

```
docker ps -l
```

First problem: here nothing happends. The browser is showing an empty page (ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Further more in the guide it is explained, that for Mac you can check your ip address via the command:

```
docker-machine ip your_vm_name
```

Here appears the second problem: This command results in an error-message:

```
Host does not exist: "your_vm_name"
```

So my questions are:

How to set up the virtual machine (or "your_vm_name" respectively)? 
Does it have to do anything with the vhosts file on my Mac OS?
Is there mybe a conflict with MAMP (which I'm also using sometimes)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

And thanks to GianArb for the very fast answer! That solution works as well.

Just to contribute to the community, I just found out by myself, that the solution was too simple to be true.

Instead of your-vm-name use default (obviously the default-host that is set up by docker), so I just used:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

and then I got the right IP.

Comment: Perfect! You can use your /etc/hosts to have a readable address, usually i don't use localhost.. you can use something like docker.local +1

Answer (score 0):

Hello the process to start to use docker on mac with docker-machine is like:

Create a new docker machine on virtualbox, you can use a name like "your_vm_name" or just "default" in this way you can not use the name because "default" is a keyword that docker-machine try to use when you don't specify nothing.

The problem here is, why docker-machine ip your_vm_name doesn't provide the good ip? Can you copy the result of your command

```
echo $DOCKER_HOST
```

Usually it's 192.168.99.100 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Actual for Mac OS:
If there is no real need in VirtualBox machine you can just remove it.
Docker can start Linux containers under Mac OS without any VirtualBox machines.
Without any VirtualBox machines, all exported ports are available on the `localhost:*`.

1. Remove docker machine

   ```
   docker-machine ls
   docker-machine stop default
   docker-machine rm default
   ```
2. Make sure that you don't have the command `eval $(docker-machine env ...)` in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`.
   Otherwise, nothing will work. You will see the error `Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists`.
3. By the default configuration no need to have any env variables like `$DOCKER_*`
4. In my case, the only docker installed by downloading a .dmg image from the official site works without any problems. Any versions installed via `brew` didn't work out of the box.

PS: tested on Mac OS 10.13 and 10.14